Spinning mass around Spring with gravity
I've seen similar posts, but none in which a mass rotates vertically while connected to a spring, with gravity acting on the mass. I want to know if the path of the mass can be described with elementary functions or if an ODE with a single function exists. I've tried describing the problem with a differential equation, but did not get far because the velocity is not constant and the path is not circular.
I apologize if someone else has asked this question; I'm not too familiar with this site.

Put the base of the spring at $(0,0)$. The force on the mass is $\mathbf{F}=-k(x,y)-mg\hat{y},$ so
\begin{align*}
m\ddot{x}&=-kx \\
m\ddot{y}&=-ky-mg.
\end{align*}
The $x$ component is just SHM. To make the $y$ component homogenous, define $y_1\equiv y+\frac{mg}{k},$ so that
$$m\ddot{y}_1=-ky_1,$$
allowing you to solve for $y_1,$ and hence $y$. You should find that the trajectory is an ellipse with center shifted downwards by $mg/k.$

I thought we also had to account for the zentripital force of the mass. If so, I dont know how to because the centripital force depends on $\phi$(t) which is not constant.

Your correct that the centripetal force is not constant, which is a clue that it is not useful to use in finding the trajectory for this problem. Fortunately, since the spring force is linear the x and y equations can be decoupled and solved. It turns out that both the inverse-square gravitational force and the linear Hooke force yield elliptical solutions - Bertrand's theorem rules out closed solutions entirely for other power-law potentials.
